# C# servercode to VB

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, base64

I have this code in C#.

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgScreenshot" ImageUrl="<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Screenshot")) %>"
```

It converts the varbinary image to a img and displays it. This works perfect in C#, but can't get it working in my VB.net project. Getting the

> "Servercode is not properly coded".

Can anyone help me convert it to VB?

Comment: I doubt this works in C# because it would complain about the quotes just the same. Inside your attribute `ImageUrl="..."` you need to use single quotes (or outside and use double quotes inside).

Comment: Well, the `ImageUrl` attribute will trigger `Server tag is not well-formed` problem, since double quotes used inside other double quotes. You should use double quotes only inside `<%...%>` and use `String.Format` to concatenate string with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vb.net "&" is the concatenation operator and an array is defined with parentheses "()" instead of brackets "[]". Also, type conversion syntax is a bit different.

I believe this would be the conversion from C# to VB.net:

```
ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," & Convert.ToBase64String(CType(Eval("Screenshot"), Byte()))%>'
```

Alternatively as mentioned in the comments you can use the `string.format` method:

```
ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("data:Image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(CType(Eval("Screenshot"), Byte())))%>'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. The first one worked great, but String.format isn't working just to note.

Comment: @LukeRemming Okay, I will fix it, and update the answer. I did not actually test these. :)

Comment: @LukeRemming I made the update with the correct syntax, but could not get the string.format to work locally with inline tags. Since you are only concatenating two strings the `&` should be fine.